# Ms access VBA select case

Tags: vba, ms-access

My code is running on different tables, so each table has different number of rows.

I would like to have `SELECT CASE nLine` so I can group them to 5 rows.

Where each group while have different code according to row.

row = 1 will have code 1.

row 2 - 4 will have code 2.

row = 5 will have code 5.

```
Select Case nLine
    Case 1
       Code 1
    Case 2 - 4
       Code 2
    Case 5
       Code 3
End Select
Loop <===Start again from above SELECT CASE
```

So, I need a code to group my rows to 5rows per group. And on each Group, to run this code.

Comment: How do you decide the row number?  What if the table's resorted? I'm asking as the order of rows is irrelevant for a relational database - it's all about the relationship between data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the purpose of this grouping?  If it's for display purposes create a calculated field in a query and use that.

```
GroupNo: IIf([nLine] = 1,1,IIf([nLine] = 5,3, 2))
```